# SQL Server stored procedure send_dbmail failure in Google Account

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I'm having problems with the `send_dbmail` procedure. I configured all with SSL enabled.

If I send through port 465, I get this error:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2021-07-22T10:25:46). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.)

And if I send through port 587, I get another error:

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure (Sending Mail using Account 3 (2021-07-22T10:10:26).
> Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure)

I tried to telnet and both ports are accessible from the server.

Can someone give me a hand?

That's the code to create and execute the test.

Sure, the code is the following.

```
-- CONFIG PROFILE & ACCOUNT --

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
    @account_name = 'MAIL'
   ,@description = 'Send mail SQL Server Stored Procedure'
   ,@email_address = 'XXX@XXXXX.com'
   ,@display_name = 'XXXX'
   ,@replyto_address = 'XXXX@XXXXX.com'
   ,@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   ,@username = 'XXXX@XXXXX.com'
   ,@password = 'XXXXXXXX'
   ,@port = 587
   ,@enable_ssl = 1
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
    @profile_name = 'XXXXXXX'
   ,@description = 'Send mail SQL Server Stored Procedure'
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
    @profile_name = 'XXXXXX'
   ,@account_name = 'XXXXXX'
   ,@sequence_number = 1
GO
--TEST--
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'XXXXXXX'
   ,@recipients = 'testmail@XXXXX.com'
   ,@subject = 'Email from SQL Server'
   ,@body = 'TESTTTTT :)'
   ,@importance ='HIGH'
GO
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code with the full settings (obscuring private info obviously). Is the Gmail account open for unsecure connections?

Comment: Doesn't sound like SQL Server trusts Gmail's X.509 certificate. Which would be highly unusual. Is this a recent Windows Server version with all Windows Updates applied? It's possible to manually use `openssl s_client` to capture the public key portion of the X.509 certificate, which you could save to a .crt file to import into the Local Machine Certificate's store, but it sounds like Windows Updates are out of date having not installed recent (any?) Trusted Root Certificates updates.

Comment: Another possibility came to mind: perhaps you're on a corporate network or an ISP operating a Cisco PIX-like appliance. These can be configured to intercept SMTP traffic and disrupt STARTSSL traffic so that they can inspect all mail flows. Testing with `openssl s_client` could confirm whether or not that's the case.